# C# Method overloading resolution

Tags: c#, overloading

I have these Methods:

```
    static void OverloadedMethod(Action<ulong> handlerAction)
    {            
    }

    static void OverloadedMethod(Action<float> handlerAction)
    {
    }

    static void HandlerA(ulong dataProgress)
    {
    }

    static void HandlerB(float dataProgress)
    {
    }
```

I can call

```
OverloadedMethod(HandlerA);
```

without problems, but if i try to call

```
OverloadedMethod(HandlerB);
```

Compiler complains: Ambiguous Invocation.

I have read [this article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) but i dont understand why the compiler knows which method should it choose if the parameter is a ulong but it cannot resolve the same situation if the parameter is a float...

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4.aspx), there is a pre-defined implicit conversion from ulong to float.  As a result, the implicit conversion prevents the compiler from identifying which method to call.

Comment: But if we have methods like `static void SomeMethod(float a){Console.WriteLine("In float method");}` and `static void SomeMethod(ulong a) { Console.WriteLine("In ulong method");}` and call it like `SomeMethod(10);` then it correctly resolves and there is no ambiguous error from compiler.  So not really sure if it is implicit conversion preventing overload resolution.

Comment: This is standard type conversion, we are talking generic types here, there is no implicit casting for generics.

Comment: @BartoszKP, after reading your answer: so, as a float can be a float or a float implicitly converted from ulong _implicit conversion occurs and neither of them is better_. But as a ulong cannot be implicitly obtained from a float there is no doubt, right ?

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at covariance and contravariance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Link-only answers are not generally acceptable. Include the link in your answer, but you need to summarize the relevant bits directly in your post here.